# How to make a GET (app.get) take two tables or allow me to do more functions

Tags: mysql, node.js, ejs

I need some help
I have a final project for university and I have decided to do it with
NodeJS
EJS
MySQL

But I have not been able to solve this error that I know it may sound stupid but I am new to this, I have the following code to get;

```
    connection.query('SELECT u.id_users,u.name_users,u.surname_users,u.email_users, t.desc_typeusers FROM users u INNER JOIN type_users t ON u.id_type_users = t.id_type_users', 
    function(error, results){
        if(error){
            console.log(error);
        } else{
            res.render("./admuser",
            {
                usert:'Express', desc_typeusers_data: results, results:results
            }
            );
        } 
        
    })
})
```

But my drop-down list obviously shows the three types of user, because my table looks like this
[Aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pN1IB.png)

I thought I could do something like this, but I don't know if it's possible.

```
    connection.query('SELECT desc_typeusers FROM type_users', function(error, data){
        if(error){
            console.log(error);
        } else{
            res.render("./admuser",{usert:'Express', desc_typeusers_data: data});
        } 
        
    }
    ,connection.query('SELECT * FROM users',  (error, results)=>{
        if(error){
            console.log(error);
        }else{
            res.render('./admuser',{
                results:results
            },{
                usert:'Express', desc_typeusers_data: data
            })
        }
    })
    )
})
```

I don't know if it is possible, or if someone can explain a little bit about it.
Thank you very much

Comment: Tip: Your life is going to be a *lot* easier if you can use `async` and `await` here. Managing callbacks like this is an absolute mess.

Comment: Are you asking "How do I run two queries, and combine the results in the response?" With callbacks you have to nest it, one inside the other's callback function, which can lead to some utterly absurd levels of nesting even if you're careful. This is why Promise-based code is way easier to follow.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Thank you @tadman You are right, I had no knowledge in promise, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root issue here is that you can only call `res.render()` ONCE per request.  You only get to send one response to the http request.

So, that means you have to gather ALL your data and then when you have it all, then call `res.render()` and pass it all the data at once.

With the plain callback database API, that generally means you nest the two requests like this:

```
connection.query('SELECT desc_typeusers FROM type_users', function(error, data) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.sendStatus(500);
        return;
    }
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM users', (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
            res.sendStatus(500);
            return;
        }
        res.render('./admuser', {
            results: results,
            usert: 'Express',
            desc_typeusers_data: data
        });
    });
});
```

If you use the promise-based API to your database in the mysql2 module, then you can use `Promise.all()` and run both queries in parallel (probably leading to a faster response) and use `Promise.all()` to tell you when both queries are done and what their results are.

Comment: Thank you very much @amigo00 you saved my life, I think I will start to apply promise, I'm looking into it.